# Sidebar full height

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I make my sidebar full height of the screen without using position: fixed? I tried with this code, but it doesn't feel right. Any suggestions?

JSFindle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pw4FN/57/

```
if($(window).height() > $('#page-container').height()){
    $('#menu').css("min-height", $(window).height());
}else{
    $('#menu').css("min-height", $('#page-container').height());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div to have the full height of the screen:

```
#min-height {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because when you scroll the div ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a table:

https://jsfiddle.net/q7ch74Ly/

```
html {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table-row;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar + .content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html, .sidebar, .sidebar + .content {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```